# How extract single frame from video stream using gstreamer / closing stream

Tags: shell, command-line, gstreamer, rtsp

I need to take one frame from video stream from web camera and write it to the file.
In ffmpeg I could do it in this way:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.6.101.40:554/video.3gp -t 1 img.png
```

My GStreamer command:

```
gst-launch-1.0  rtspsrc location="rtsp://10.6.101.40:554/video.3gp" is_live=true ! decodebin ! jpegenc ! filesink location=img.jpg
```

problem is, gstreamer process keeps running and does not end. How can I take only one frame and force stream to close after file is written?
Is it possible to do this from command line or should I code this in c/python etc...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do this with:

```
! jpegenc snapshot=TRUE
```

See [jpegenc - snapshot](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-jpegenc.html#GstJpegEnc--snapshot).

but my source is different so your mileage may vary.

Comment: To be honest, I am not able to re-run this. Abandoned old long gone project, I am going accept this as an answer and hope for it is correct. Thanks a lot.

Comment: there was an issue with `rtph26xdepay` (which is internally used by `rtspsrc`) https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/-/issues/535 - this means that until this was fixed, the pipeline never ended. I have to use it now with older gstreamer so I use this "hack" with `identity` element: `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://<url>"  ! decodebin  ! jpegenc snapshot=true ! identity error-after=2 ! filesink location=image.jpeg` (Note you need to send error after 2nd buffer, to be able to save the 1st one)

Comment: I am using gstreamer 1.16.2 and the answer didn't work for me due to the reason explained by @JanSpurny . His hack with identity worked fine though.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the property `number of buffers` for element `queue`, and restrict it to 1. This will give you hopefully a single frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, but I was not able to make it working.

Comment: This will just limit the queue to holding one frame at a time, but it will still pass all the frames downstream.